# React.js update state property to a new object

Tags: reactjs

After componentDidMount `quote` is equal to `{id: 16, text: "Be yourself; everyone else is already taken.", author: "Oscar Wilde", next_id: 18, previous_id: null}`

When I click `next`, componentWillRecieveProps is invoked and tries to update `quote` to another object. I get an error. the same if I try to change it to a string. But when I try to change `quote` to a number or boolean, it works.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchQuote(16)
}

fetchQuote(id) {
  axios.get(`api/quotes/${id}`)
  .then(response => {
    console.log("Data: ", response.data);
    this.setState({
      quote: response.data
    }, ()=> {console.log("fetch: ", this.state);})
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
    this.setState({ fireRedirect: true })
  })
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.qsParams = queryString.parse(nextProps.location.search)
  this.quoteId = Number(this.qsParams.quote)
  this.fetchQuote(this.quoteId)
```

}

`componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` successful triggers `fetchQuote` and that function makes a request and gets right data which is an object, but can't change `quote` to that received data

Errors:

```
1) warning.js?6327:33 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- 
expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for 
composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export 
your component from the file it's defined in.

Check the render method of `QuotesDisplay`.
in QuotesDisplay (created by Route)
in Route (created by App)
in div (created by App)
in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
in BrowserRouter (created by App)
in App
in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
in BrowserRouter

2) Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected 
a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite 
components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your 
component from the file it's defined in.

Check the render method of `QuotesDisplay`.
at invariant (invariant.js?7313:42)
at createFiberFromElementType (react-dom.development.js?cada:8185)
at createFiberFromElement (react-dom.development.js?cada:8130)
at reconcileSingleElement (react-dom.development.js?cada:9378)
at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js?cada:9477)
at reconcileChildrenAtPriority (react-dom.development.js?cada:10127)
at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js?cada:10118)
at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js?cada:10370)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js?cada:10609)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?cada:12573)

3) The above error occurred in the 
<div> component:
in div (created by QuotesDisplay)
in div (created by QuotesDisplay)
in QuotesDisplay (created by Route)
in Route (created by App)
in div (created by App)
in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
in BrowserRouter (created by App)
in App
in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
in BrowserRouter

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error 
handling behavior.

4) Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error 
was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in 
development.
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js?cada:1345)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js?cada:1195)
at performWork (react-dom.development.js?cada:12800)
at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js?cada:13244)
at performFiberBatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js?cada:1646)
at stackBatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js?cada:1637)
at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js?cada:1651)
at Object.batchedUpdatesWithControlledComponents [as batchedUpdates] 
(react-dom.development.js?cada:1664)
at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js?cada:1874)
```

Comment: Why are you calling `this.fetchQuote` inside the `componentWillReceiveProps`?
Why don't just call `this.fetchQuote` when you click on `next`?

Comment: I'm debugging a code of someone else: it was `componentWillReceiveProps` there already. 
I tried to do the way you asked about, but errors are absolutely same.

Comment: Can you put the error you see. Maybe with the error description  we can help you to understand what is happening.

Comment: Sure, I updated my question.

Comment: Mmmm, what I think is happening  is that you are validating some data based on your state and you are returning nothing in some cases, so the render method is crashing.
Can you put all the code of that component? . Because it seems the issue is inside the render method or inside some function the render method calls. So I need to see all de component code to try to find the root of the error.